# Python - Numbers are in a reversed order using camelot to read PDF to excel

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, python-camelot

I'm using library camelot to read PDF and export as excel with Python. I tried two sets of PDF forms. For one set of the forms, it works perfectly. For another set of PDF forms, the number came out in a reversed order. Does anyone know what causes it and how to fix it so that the numbers are in a normal order.

[image: Below is what is in PDF and what comes out in Camelot]

Here's the link to the PDF: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AOo6a8eBt3-v_UU_OT2p99p3TeW-kK8t/view?usp=sharing.

Here's the major part of the code:

```
tables=camelot.read_pdf(SchE_pdf,pages="all")
SchExlsx = ExcelWriter('5471 SchE.xlsx')
for i in list:
    tables[i]
    tables[i].parsing_report
    tables[i].to_excel(SchExlsx,sheet_name=str(i))
```

Comment: Can you post the original PDF?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I've just uploaded the PDF link and the code. Thank you so much for looking into this!!!

Comment: Probably there are some problems with your PDF.

Comment: @yanjunzhang Did you make sure this is not the problem with ExcelWriter?!